# Generating Random Numbers Struck in Loop

Tags: java, loops, random

I am now writing a JAVA program to produce 10 distinct random numbers between 100 and a random number less than 100 (inclusive) and display them in sorted order. Here is the code I wrote

```
Random rnd = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> rndNums = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
int max = 0;
while(rndNums.size() < 10) {
    if(rndNums.size() == 0)
        max = rnd.nextInt(101);
    int num = rnd.nextInt(101);
    if(num >= max || rndNums.contains(num))
        continue;
    rndNums.add(num);
}   
Collections.sort(rndNums);
for(int i : rndNums)
    System.out.println (i);
```

But the program sometimes struck in loop. I can’t find what the fault that cause is. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: *"...and a random number less than 100 (inclusive)..."* So that would be...less than 101, then. Or less than or equal to 100.

Comment: Use a HashSet to make the numbers unique and I think this question has been asked before. Look around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this code produces ten distinct random numbers from 0 to 100 (inclusive), when it works.

The problem is when `max` is chosen to less than 10 and `num` is chosen less than `max`, there is no possible way to get ten distinct numbers, so the code loops forever. For example, if `max` is set to 5 and `num` is set to 3, the 3 will be added to `rndNums` and the loop will continue, but the only numbers that can be added after that are 0, 1, 2, and 4, which will be exhausted when `rndNums.size()` is 5, at which point the code loops forever, since it has exhausted all possibilities and `rndNums` has less than 10 elements.

You could initialize `max` to `10 + rnd.nextInt(91)` to prevent this from happening, and you wouldn't even need to put it in the loop since you're guaranteed to get ten numbers less than `max`. Then you can set `num` to `rnd.nextInt(max)` in your loop for greater efficiency.

If you really want numbers "between 100 and a random number less than 100 (inclusive)". then use `max = rnd.nextInt(92);` and `num = max + rnd.nextInt(101 - max);`.

Answer (score 2):

On the first iteration you set `max` to a random number between `0` and `101`. You then disacrd all numbers greater than that number.

What numbers would you discard if `max` is `0`? I'd say all of them - you will never manage to find `10` distinct positive integers less than `0`, or `5` for that matter.

Essentially - if your `max` value is less than `10` you will loop forever.

Comment: Thanks you, from your answer, I now know what the fault is.